# Use office icon in Add in Ribbon

Tags: visual-studio-2012, add-in, ribbon, office-2013

I create an Add-In with VS2012 for Office 2010/2013.
I want to use an office embedded icon for my RibbonButton, but I have to use external resources.

Can I use this panel of icon with my Ribbon ?

[image]

If not, can I extract these icons, and in which file ? (I already look in Office15 directory, extracted all resources in files, but I did'nt find the print icon for example.)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the ImageMSO attribute of the ribbon control. This allows developers to use standard Microsoft Office icons although I'm not sure what you mean by you have to use external resources. This package will help you to visually search, extract and save the icons you seek from Microsoft Excel to use with your ribbon.

[Microsoft Office Icons (ImageMSO) Gallery & Extraction](https://imagemso.codeplex.com/)

[image: ImageMSO Gallery on Microsoft Excel 2013 running Windows 8]